# Best way to limit number of threads running certain section of code in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm looking for a way to limit number of threads which can run certain section of code in Java using Semaphores or similar.

We were looking into something similar to [Google Guava RateLimiter](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) - but instead of limiting number calls per second we need to limit number of threads to run critical section of code.

The reason why need this is that certain library we are using has issues here so we just looking for a quick workaround.

Comment: Why can't you use java.util.concurrent.Semaphore?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is exactly what `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore` was designed to do. You create a `Semaphore` like so:

```
final int MAX_NOF_THREADS = 5;
final Semaphore mySemaphore = new Semaphore(MAX_NOF_THREADS);
```

then for the critical area you'd do:

```
try {
    mySemaphore.aquire(); // This will hang until there is a vacancy
    do_my_critical_stuff();
} finally {
    mySemaphore.release();
}
```

... as simple as that.

Comment: I totally agree on `Semaphore`s, they should be the first choice for this task. Though, there's one thing worth mentioning: Technically, one thread is allowed to make multiple acquiring's. It means that some logical errors (an ill-conceived recursion, for example) might lead to underutilization of threads or even to a deadlock. But if used carefully, they are the right tool here.

Comment: This code might yield a bug: If the thread is interrupted while waiting on the aquire() method, it will both not aquire the permit and release one additional permit...

Comment: @user1028741 That should be resolved by using `mySemaphore.acquireUninterruptibly()` instead?

Answer (score 10):

Though, `Semaphore` is the best choice here (look at the @Bex's answer) if you're careful, it's also possible to use `ExecutorService`. Just wrap the piece of code you'd like to protect from unlimited concurrent access into a `Callable` task and submit such tasks to the executor service:

```
// Task that will be executed
public class MyTask implements Callable<Void> {
    @Override
    public Void call() {
        // Do the work here
        return null;
    }
}

// Service to execute tasks in no more than 5 parallel threads
// Cache it after creation and use when you need to execute a task
int maxThreadsCount = 5;
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxThreadsCount);

// Execute a task. It will wait if all 5 threads are busy right now.
executor.submit(new MyTask());
```

With `ExecutorService` you can also use `Runnable` instead of `Callable`, `invokeAll()` instead of `execute`, wait for task completion, cancel tasks, return values from them and do some other useful things.

Java 8 makes it simpler, you can use lambdas instead of defining task classes:

```
executor.submit(() -> {
    // Do the work here
});
```

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that the Executors factory builds ExecutorService implementations which are backed by unbounded job queues.  Depending on frequency and how long the running jobs take, this can have a negative impact on the system. In some cases it can bring down applications because of the number of jobs queued in memory.  In those cases, it may be worth creating your own **ThreadPoolExecutor** with a bounded work queue and a custom **RejectedExecutionHandler**.  Seeing as how the section of code is critical, you probably want the unbounded version.  Just be aware of the impacts.